# should imports/includes count in golf

Tags: discussion, code-golf

follow the title

mainly I'm asking this so I know whether to count all the import declarations that are required for the code to run successfully (especially when the import/include is required in the language like in D)

Comment: This has been discussed in various oblique ways: [Language Handicap](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/185/78), [Using libraries in solutions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/188/78), [Should non-standard compiler flags be included in character counts?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19/78), [Shebangs; yes or no?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/84/78), [C/C++ golfing: Should undefined behaviour be allowed?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/21/78).

Answer (score 11):

I *always* count them in my c solutions, though people will sometimes omit to include `stdio.h` if they only use functions like `printf` and `getc` that will compiler correctly with the type defaulting behavior of K&R or ansi c.